# How to use argparse to list options

Tags: python, argparse

Here is sample code:

```
import argparse

fruit_choices = [
    'banana', 
    'pear', 
    'apple',
    'mango',
    'list',  # this will list all the fruit in a user-friendly way
]

ap = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Fruit selector')
ap.add_argument('-u', '--utensil', dest='utensil', required=True, 
                help='Utensil used to eat fruit.')
ap.add_argument('-f', '--fruit', dest='fruit', required=True, choices=fruit_choices, 
                help='Fruit. Use "list" to see all options.', metavar='')

args = ap.parse_args()

if args.fruit == 'list':
    print '\n'.join(fruit_choices)
```

While this works, I want the functionality similar to many Linux tools where a parameter such as 'list' will list all of the fruit.

The problem is that since the first argument is required, it will never get to that switch. I know I can make none of them required and then handle the checks for required parameters myself, but is there a (designed) way to do this with with argparse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to accept an commandline without the `-u' option then it really isn't required.  You want it in most circumstances, but not all.

If you define `fruit` like this:

```
ap.add_argument('-f', '--fruit', dest='fruit', choices=fruit_choices, 
            help='Fruit')
```

then '-h' will include that list of fruit names.  That is the designed method in argparse.

That is, admittedly a bit of a problem if the list of choices is too long or messy.

In general you want to stay away from defining 'optionals' with 'required=True'.  `argparse` lets you do that, but it does not always fit well.

You might also look at `subparsers`.  You could for example define a 'list' subparser.  But you would have to define another subparser for other actions such as `eat`.

We could, in theory, define a special Action class, that would behave like `help` and `version`, displaying the list, and then exiting without processing the other arguments.  But that may be too advanced for the current problem.